# Adding event listener to dynamically inserted elements?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-propagation

I'm inserting this html dynamically:

````
   <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDivLeft"></div>
      <div class="innerDivRight"></div>
    </div>```
````

And I want to add an event listener to the outerDiv.
This is what I've tried:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList = "outerDiv") {
       console.log("e.target")
  }
});
```

My problem is that when I click inside the "outerDiv", often e.target ===  "innerDivLeft" or "innerDivRight" and that means that the event is not firing. How can I make sure that e.target === "outerDiv"

Comment: = is assignment

Comment: I am guessing you did not look at the documentation for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList which has a method that says if a class is there...